# Vertical lines on netbook LCD display--fixable? Cause?

Tags: lcd

I have an Asus Eee PC 1000HA netbook, which I've been happy with for years.  Lately there have been some vertical blue lines in the upper-right quadrant of the display.  They don't show up on screen captures, so they're clearly hardware rather than software related.  They also appear both in Windows XP and Debian GNU/Linux.

I am not very familiar with LCD hardware.  Would this be the result of a loose connector, or physical damage to the LCD panel itself, or a timing chip, or what?  If I find a junk 1000HA somewhere, could I swap out the panel?  I'm not afraid of a screwdriver and I dont mind cracking cases.  I did look online for replacment panels, but all the larger suppliers seem to be out. It's an old system for a netbook and I suspect parts haven't been made for a while.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: parts could probably still be found on e-bay or other tech-centric auction sites.

Comment: Yeah, looking on eBay and Craig's list was my plan if I do go with replacing the panel. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked to a friend of mine who's a computer consultant this weekend. When I powered the thing up, all but one of the lines was gone!  He diagnosed the problem as a loose connection between the video chipset and the LCD panel--when it jiggles into just the right position, the screen is fine. If I shake it, I can make it go back to eight lines across the display.  I'll try taking the thing apart and re-connecting the loose cable.

Comment: For the benefit of any future readers: the problem turned out to be that one of the hinges had popped out of alignment. When I snapped the hinge back into place (with three fingers) it worked perfectly and it's still working now, months later.

Answer (score 0):

If they're not spaced out evenly then it's probably localized damage, and replacing the panel would be sufficient. If they are evenly spaced out or appear across the entire display (the spread of lines, not the lines themselves) then it may be indicative of a deeper problem.

Comment: Yeah, localized but higbly parallel, and seemingly progressive.  It started as four lines, now it's eight.  I should have put that in the question ....

Comment: Hrm. That does sound like something in logic then. Still panel-side probably though.